# How should I understand when a word is not in DWDS, but in the literature?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

While reading a modern novel in German, Alles Licht, das wir nicht sehen, I came across the word, "Verrieseln":

> Kalte Winde blasen vom Atlantik heran, und Etienne verbarrikadiert sich im alten Zimmer seines Bruders, während Marie-Laure das langsame **Verrieseln** der Stunden damit durchsteht, mit den Händen über die Muscheln im Zimmer des Onkels zu streichen und sie nach Größe und Art zu ordnen, nach ihrer Form, und wieder und wieder überprüft sie ihr Werk und versucht, sich zu versichern, dass sie nicht eine einzige falsch eingeordnet hat.

Neither DWDS nor Duden give reference to this word, but there are many examples of its use in [DWDS Textkorpera](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=verrieseln&corpus=zeit&date-start=1946&date-end=2018&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50). How should I understand the use of this word? Is it standard German? Where is it defined?

Comment: Re your last two questions: no, *verrieseln* is not standard German. It is uncommon, literary usage. German speakers will immediately understand it, but if you use it in everyday conversation or a non-literary text, you will get raised eyebrows. I have been using German for near 50 years now, have never come across this word, but had no problems whatsoever in parsing it. (It helps that Germans are very used to *Vorsilben* like *ver-* in front of many, many different words.)

Comment: Actually, the word seems to have several meanings: For instance, when growing grapes, it describes  a process, where flowers or berries drop to the ground due to harsh weather conditions. Aside from this, we have the word "rieseln", and as analoguous constructions, where "rinnen" leads to "verrinnen", we can construct "verrieseln" out of "rieseln". While the word is not in Duden, its meaning is clear from your context.

Comment: @user1934428 There is another meaning: Let sewage seep on fields ([*verrieseln*](http://www.wasser-wissen.de/abwasserlexikon/v/verrieselungvonabwasser.htm)) so that it gets filtered by the dirt on the way to the ground water. Berlin had expansive [*Rieselfelder*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berliner_Rieselfelder) for that purpose, some of them until recently, before proper sewage treatment plants were installed. Perhaps the translator didn't know about that or he would not have used that word.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica : Amazing: Such a rare word, and so many meanings.

Comment: I see that the original says "endures the slow rain of hours", so there is a connection to precipitation, even though "rieseln" is typically used with snow ("leise rieselt der Schnee"). *Tröpfeln" is perhaps *too* slow.... *verrieseln* is not bad. Simply translate "rain" as *Regen* would perhaps work as well as the original. I'm glad I'm not a translator!

Answer (score 5):

This is just one way to describe *passing of time*. There are a couple of verbs to creatively rephrase that, to achieve a more colorful expression:

- vergehen (similar to *passing*, very neutral)
- verfließen (considering the time as something liquid)
- verrinnen (also liquid)
- verrieseln (considering the time as fine granules as in an hourglass, which I suspect as picture intended here)

Unfortunately different ad-hoc verb compositions may be formed with the same meaning as well.

You may note, that all these verbs start with *ver-* prefix, which I consider as appropriate, since the time is irreversibly lost (cf. *verloren*) afterwards.

Comment: I would appreciate an opinion on the question I placed below.

Comment: @user44591 The answer is no. But feel free to ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the word as is in Duden for example, in this case, you can take the word apart. "Verrieseln" is made out of the prefix "ver-" and the actual verb stem "rieseln".

If you now search Duden for "rieseln", I think the meanings fit to your book quote, for example:

> mit feinem, hellem, gleichmäßigem Geräusch in vielen kleinen Teilchen leise, kaum hörbar nach unten fallen, gleiten, sinken

The "ver-" prefix makes the whole thing sound a bit more unfortunate, like it wasn't intended to happen. For example "verlesen" or "verschrieben" both mean mistakes in the action itself.

[Here](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/rieseln#google_vignette) is the link to the Duden entry that I found.

Comment: The “ver-“ here is more like “away”, i.e. the time “rieselt” away.

Comment: So, am I free to add the prefix "ver-" to any German verb I like (which is not already prefixed with it, of course) and assume that it is reasonable to expect that my meaning can be understood, provided I use the prefix according to the conventional meaning of the prefix? If so, must I apply some (unknown) cognizance toward any prefixes already attached to the verb I am prefixing?

Comment: Examples of prefixed verbs, further prefixed with ver-: vernachlässigen, verabreichen, verabschieden, verunglücken, verunsichern

Comment: Re "am I free to add the prefix "ver-" to any German verb": At least in poetic language, where you have some poetic license, or in other "creative" situations (teenage banter etc.) I think pretty much yes. After all, this is one of the ways language evolves: One tries something out, and if it fits a need and is in some way "attractive" (efficient or poetic or cool or fills a semantic niche or sounds great etc.) people pick it up and it may stick. That said, a German teacher (even in Germany) in 5th grade may till mark it as an error.